# Como resolver mejor este bucle

Tags: python

Buenas ¿Como puedo resolver este bucle? Vi alternativas pero mostraban varias listas y este no es el caso. Mi objetivo es resolver la concatenación de variables en un bucle, pero entiendo que no es la forma correcta.

```
nombre = "Javier"
frutas = ["manzana", "banana", "naranja"]

for i in range(5):
    print(i,") La fruta favorita de",nombre,"es la", frutas[i])
```

Se me ocurrio esta forma, pero lo veo, muy poco elegante

```
nombre = "Javier"
frutas = ["manzana", "banana", "naranja"]

for i in range(3):
    texto = str(i) + ') La fruta favorita de ' + nombre + ' es la ' + str(frutas[int(i)])
    print(texto)
```

Estoy aprendiendo Python y tengo muchas dudas ya que normalmente programo en Javascript. Saludos

Comment: En js existen los templates string, en python se llaman `f-strings` investiga sobre ello

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas utilizando las cadenas formateados. Aquí unos ejemmplos:

1. Utilizando `for in`

   ```
   print([f"la fruta favorita de {nombre} es la {fruta}" for fruta in frutas])
   ```

Resultado:

```
   La fruta favorita de Javier es manzana
   La La fruta favorita de Javier es banana
   La fruta favorita de Javier es naranja
```

Las cadenas de texto en python se encierran entre comillas doble o simples. Si a estas cadenas le antecedes una `f`, como en el ejemplo, entonces puedes incluir variables dentro de estas. Las variables tienen que estar entre llaves `{}`. Es así que `{nombre}` hace referencia a la variable `nombre` y por lo tanto, pondrá el valor de este. Estas cadenas se les conoce como `f-strings`. Ad8cionalmente puedes aplicarle formato.

El `for in` es el equivalente a un `for` normal a diferencia que este se encuentra despues del cuerpo de lo que vendría en un `for` normal. En ejemplo, observarás que hay una variable `fruta`, esta viene definida en `for fruta`. El `in frutas` significa que `fruta` va a tomar el valor de cada elemento del arreglo. El equivalente seria:

```
    for fruta in frutas:
        
         print(f"la fruta favorita de {nombre} es la {fruta}")
```

Si quieres enumerar la salida entonces utilizas `enumerate`

```
 print([f"{n}. la fruta favorita de {nombre} es la {fruta}" for n,fruta in enumerate(frutas)])
```

2. Utilizando `join`

   ```
   print(f"Las frutas favoritas de {nombre} son {', '.join(frutas)}")
   ```

Resultado;

```
   Las frutas favoritas de Javier son manzana, banana, naranja
```

Esta opción es si quieres poner las frutas en una sola frase. A diferencia del ejemplo anterior que imprime una frase por cada fruta y sin utilizar un `for`. El `', '.join(frutas)` hace que el arreglo lo junte separado por`', '`.

3. Utilizando la selección al azar de la fruta:

   ```
   import random 
   print(f"la fruta  favorita de {nombre} es  {random.choice(frutas)}")
   ```

Resultado:

```
   La fruta favorita de Javier es naranja
```

Aquí se utiliza `random` para que seleccione una fruta al azar. Observa que random está entre llaves lo que significa que puedes incluir algunas funciones.

Answer (score 3):

Dos cosas:

1. No necesitas concatenar cadenas. Puedes usar f-strings que te evitan la concatenación y por tanto también el tener que andar usando `str()` alrededor de las variables.
2. No necesitas iterar por los índices con un `for i in range()`. Puedes iterar directamente por las frutas con un `for fruta in frutas`. Eso evita la incómoda sintaxis `frutas[i]` para acceder a cada fruta. Si por otro lado necesitas el valor de `i` para imprimirlo, puedes usar `enumerate()`.

Juntando ambas ideas tu código puede quedar así:

```
nombre = "Javier"
frutas = ["manzana", "banana", "naranja"]

for i, fruta in enumerate(frutas):
    print(f"{i}) La fruta favorita de {nombre} es la {fruta}")
```

Que produce el resultado que buscabas:

```
0) La fruta favorita de Javier es la manzana
1) La fruta favorita de Javier es la banana
2) La fruta favorita de Javier es la naranja
```